# Bitwise masking issues in RASDIAL APIS

Tags: c, winapi, ras, dial-up

This question is regarding Rasdial and pbk file.
I am updating the pbk file using "rassetentryproperties"  and dialling through "rasdialdlg".

The below flags decide the parameters of the pbk file inturn responisble for the property of the dial-up connection.
I am presetting the flags as:

```
RasEntry.dwfOptions = 0x00000000;
RasEntry.dwfOptions2 = 0x00000000;
```

Trying to do as below to set Flag1 and Flag2.

```
RasEntry.dwfOptions |= (Set Flag1 | Set Flag2)
```

However, my pbk file entries are not actually setting, as i set above.

Also, for the same code, Win7 pbk and win xp pbk are different. 
Where i am wrong?

Code Sample for the reference:

```
BOOL Create_Phone_Book ( LPTSTR DeviceName ) {

    DWORD regError;
    TCHAR DeviceName[100];


    if ( _tcscpy ( DeviceName, DeviceName ) != NULL ) {
        Slog ( TEXT ("Strcpy Success"), APISUCCESS );
    } else {
        Slog ( TEXT ("Strcpy Failed To copy deviceName to DeviceName"), NOLASTERROR);
        return FALSE;
    }

    RASENTRY RasEntry;
    DWORD cb;
    RASDIALPARAMS RasDialParams;

    memset((LPTSTR)&RasEntry, 0, sizeof(RASENTRY)); 

    RasEntry.dwSize = sizeof(RASENTRY);
    cb = sizeof(RASENTRY);
    regError = RasGetEntryProperties (NULL, TEXT (""), &RasEntry, &cb, NULL, NULL);

    if ( regError == ERROR_SUCCESS ) {
        Slog ( TEXT ("RasGetEntryProperties Success"), APISUCCESS );
    } else {
        RAS_ErrorHandler ( regError );
        return FALSE;
    }

    RasEntry.dwfOptions = 0x00000000;
    RasEntry.dwfOptions2 = 0x00000000;


    RasEntry.dwfOptions |= (  RASEO_IpHeaderCompression | RASEO_ModemLights |RASEO_SwCompression | 
    RASEO_ShowDialingProgress | RASEO_NetworkLogon | RASEO_DisableLcpExtensions );



    RasEntry.dwfOptions2 |= ( RASEO2_UseGlobalDeviceSettings | RASEO2_Internet );


    if ( _tcscpy ( RasEntry.szDeviceType,  RASDT_Modem ) != NULL ) {
        Slog ( TEXT ("Strcpy Success"), APISUCCESS );
    } else {
        Slog ( TEXT ("Strcpy Failed copy RASDT_MODEM to RasEntry.szDeviceType"), NOLASTERROR);
        return FALSE;
    }

    if ( _tcscpy ( RasEntry.szDeviceName, DeviceName ) != NULL ) {
        Slog ( TEXT ("Strcpy Success"), APISUCCESS );   
    } else {
        Slog ( TEXT ("Strcpy Failed copy DeviceName to RasEntry.szDeviceName"), NOLASTERROR);
        return FALSE;   
    }

    regError = RasSetEntryProperties( NULL , Dial_Up_Name, &RasEntry, sizeof(RasEntry),NULL, 0);

    if ( regError == ERROR_SUCCESS ) {
        Slog ( TEXT ("RasSetEntryProperties Succeeded"), APISUCCESS);
    } else {
        RAS_ErrorHandler ( regError );
        return FALSE;
    }

    memset((LPTSTR)&RasDialParams, 0, sizeof(RasDialParams));

    RasDialParams.dwSize = sizeof(RASDIALPARAMS);

    if ( _tcscpy (RasDialParams.szEntryName, Dial_Up_Name ) != NULL ) {
        Slog ( TEXT ("Strcpy Success"), APISUCCESS);
    } else {
        Slog ( TEXT ("Strcpy Failed Copy Dial_Up_Name to RasDialParams.szEntryName"), NOLASTERROR);
        return FALSE;
    }
    if ( _tcscpy (RasDialParams.szUserName, TEXT ("")) != NULL ) {
        Slog ( TEXT ("Strcpy Success"), APISUCCESS);    
    } else {
        Slog ( TEXT ("Strcpy Failed Copy "" to RasDialParams.szUserName"), NOLASTERROR);
        return FALSE;   
    }

    if ( _tcscpy (RasDialParams.szPassword, TEXT ("")) != NULL ) {
        Slog ( TEXT ("Strcpy Success"), APISUCCESS);    
    } else {
        Slog ( TEXT ("Strcpy Failed Copy "" to RasDialParams.szPassword"), NOLASTERROR);
        return FALSE;
    }

    regError = RasSetEntryDialParams ( NULL, &RasDialParams, FALSE);
    if ( regError == ERROR_SUCCESS ) {
        Slog ( TEXT ("RasSetEntryDialParams Success"), APISUCCESS );
    } else {
        RAS_ErrorHandler ( regError );
        return FALSE;
    }

return TRUE;

}
```

Updated 1:
Typically, i need to create an Dial-Up connection as i like. Please look at the screen shot attached.

[image]

As seen in the snap, i have to set and reset many parameters(Set-Display Progress while connecting, Reset- Prompt for UN and PW). 
These two flags use to set and reset whatever we want by "or"ing 
    RasEntry.dwfOptions
    RasEntry.dwfOptions2

So what i do in my code is :

resetting the flag:

```
RasEntry.dwfOptions = 0x00000000;

RasEntry.dwfOptions2 = 0x00000000;
```

and to set:

```
 RasEntry.dwfOptions |= (  RASEO_IpHeaderCompression | RASEO_ModemLights  
                           |RASEO_SwCompression | RASEO_ShowDialingProgress |  
                            RASEO_NetworkLogon | RASEO_DisableLcpExtensions );
```

So, the remaining flags other than the above, will be remained Unset.

Now the problem is, Whatever i am setting in the above steps are not actually setting in the dial-up connection. In another way, some parameters are not set even, if i set in the code.

What should i do to get rid of my problem?

Comment: Hello Experts... Please respond..

Comment: Nobody has responded because you didn't really ask a question. Does the code work? Presumably not? So, how does it fail? What do you expect to happen? What actually happens? What errors are reported? Etc. You've asked a lot of questions here now, you should have worked out what makes a good question by now.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks for your valuable comment. I have Updated my question.